# How the Stub communicate with the skelton

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, apache-axis, stub

I am currently working on a Axis2 Web service project. In there, a stub is used to call the server's Skelton class.

[image]

Now I want to know how the connection is taken place and how the objcts are passing from stub to the Skelton. I googled about this but couldn't find a proper explanation for this (found this like articles : http://www.coderanch.com/t/443307/Web-Services/java/Stub-Skeleton. But I expect for a deeper explanation). If any body knows a place that I can find about this please share.

Comment: You can hit the generated stub and skeleton and dive into their sources if you fail to find a satisfactory answer...

Comment: Thank you. That is what I'm doing right now Thihara. But most of the implementations are in axis2 jars. eg: _operationClient.execute(true);

Comment: Fortunately it's an open source project. So you can get the source code from apache or somewhere like grepcode. Then attach the source code in the IDE and mine away!

Comment: Hmmm....Let's go for it!

Comment: Stub serialize clients request object in to a SOAP format message, according to the wsdl definitions, and it handles the communication and post it to the endpoint of the server (which may also defined on the wsdl), the server side service receives the SOAP request and deserialize into request object and pass it skeleton so the server side class can add business logic process etc and set to response object back to serialize it and pass back to the client same way.

Comment: Thankk you Sameera. Got it!